# Is TPM2 mandatory on Linux?

Tags: linux, tpm

I have Debian and Linux 5.x kernel. I get the following error:

```
# /etc/init.d/tpm2-abrmd status
● tpm2-abrmd.service - TPM2 Access Broker and Resource Management Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tpm2-abrmd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-11-27 08:45:01 +0330; 2s ago
  Process: 5385 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/tpm2-abrmd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5385 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

`/dev/tpm0` file doesn't exist.

Does Linux need TPM?
Is it mandatory for Linux?

If it's needed, how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Linux doesn’t need a TPM (of any version).

Some programs which run on Linux do need a TPM; that’s the case of [`tpm2-abrmd`](https://packages.debian.org/tpm2-abrmd) which is the source of your error. If you don’t have a TPM (version 2) there’s no point in keeping that package installed, you should remove it.

([`tpm2-abrmd`](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-abrmd) implements [the TCG access broker and resource manager specification](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TSS-TAB-and-Resource-Manager-ver1.0-rev16_Public_Review.pdf), *i.e.* it multiplexes access to a TPM2, allowing multiple applications to share it, and therefore is only useful if a TPM2 is available in some form.)